# Firebase Firestore: The .where is not called. python

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a python program that loads an order to a treeview, this order is loaded in the form of documents in a firestore collection from firebase. When I press the order that I want to load, I call the function `loadOrder` with the necessary id to filter them. But for some reason they don't load.

This is my code:

```
def loadPedido(idTarget):
    docs = db.collection(u'slots').where(u'slotId', u'==', idTarget).stream()
    for doc in docs:
        docu = doc.to_dict()
        nombre = (docu.get('SlotName'))
        entero = (docu.get('entero'))
        valor = (docu.get('slotPrecio'))
        print(f'{doc.id} => {nombre}')
        trvPedido.insert("",'end',iid= doc.id, values=(doc.id,nombre, entero, valor))
```

`idTarget` is the id to filter, and check with a print that it arrives correctly.

i tried this:

If I write the result of the varable directly in the code, it loads correctly, like so:

```
...
docs = db.collection(u'slots').where(u'slotId', u'==', u"2996gHQ32CNFMp5vyieu").stream()
...
```

Comment: Are you sure this has anything to do with tkinter? It looks like the problem may be unrelated to tkinter.

Comment: I already removed it, I put it by mistake